# I have to remove a look like small triangle component displyed on website page title on wright side

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming

I am Designing & developing a website with help of a Wordpress theme. The link to the page where I am stuck is "https://8degreethemes.com/demos/?theme=eightmedi-lite". In this page in Page title bar, the title is appears in a box having light blue color and on the box right side bottom corner, a small triangle shape appears. I need to remove this triangle. I changed the `bg-color` of **title box** to the transparent but triangle did not change its color. Please help me to figure it out. I have shared a link of a screenshot with this to highlight the triangle. Also, the theme is free so you can easily download it and look all the files for the solution.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

that is the pseudeo :: after of your element 
in your css file 
https://8degreethemes.com/demo/8medi-lite/wp-content/themes/eightmedi-lite/style.css?ver=4.8.5 
remove this block of CSS code:

```
h1.page-title:after, .sidebar .widget-title:after{
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 15px solid #70c0e8;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I just remove these two lines, border-bottom: 15px solid #70c0e8;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;

Answer (score 0):

It is generating because of some css. You have to check where it is coming from by developer tool in chrome or any other tool.

I have checked the demo web page and found this line css line

**border-bottom: 15px solid #70c0e8;** 
in your style.css

[Have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8bFK.jpg)

Just remove it to remove that triangle, but remember if you remove this line, it will remove that triangle from all other places where this class is referenced.

Comment: Thanks, Aamir Its very helpfull.